# Using Timeline effciently

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to make Timeline start recording EXACTLY at the time where the page starts loading? I find it annoying to have to first press start and then refresh the page, because this adds some trash info in the beginning of the Timeline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such way but you can use keyboard shortcuts.

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> for start/stop recording
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for inspecting page reload

Comment: all shortcuts can be found here : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of all available shortcuts when you choose this option in DevTools (Chrome 47):
[image]